# Bracha after terrifying experience?

Tags: halacha, blessing

Recently we had a scare when we couldn't find our 4-yr old son.  For 30 minutes, we searched and panicked, called police and Hatzolah.  Finally, it was discovered that our older daughter was with him out of the house.  After such a scare that turned out ok, is there a bracha to make?

Answer (score 2):

Not to make light, but there is a famous story about Rav Bick which may or may not be true. Someone was almost in a car accident, barely missing what would have been a horrific outcome and asked the rav if he should bentch gomel. The rav responded that perhaps he himself should bentch gomel because the pants he was wearing went through the washing machine and, had he been wearing them at the time, it too would have been horrible.

The better answer is in a tshuva from Rav Moshe who differentiates between flying in a plane and driving in a car as it pertains to making a birchas gomel. He says that flying requires a bracha insofar as a person up in the air is outside the normal world situation and relying on Hashem's direct hashgacha; as opposed to driving in a car, which is a normal, everyday situation. Your child, baruch Hashem, never left our 'normal' world into Hashem's special hashgacha.

Comment: I personally don't believe that this story about Rav Bick ever happened.....when would you ever say haGomel?

Comment: When you should halachicaly. I.e. when a person is saved in a miraculous way.